# div box within another div

Tags: css, html

This should be really simple, and I thought I was doing it correctly...evidently not.

I need to get the light grey box that says "Test" into the darker grey area, to the right of the list on the left. It's supposed to be 270px tall (or whatever) and stretch to the right edge of the list on the left, and to the edge of the enclosing container on the right side.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8yLh/) with my code. Easy peasy. Thanks, guys and gals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `float: left;` to your `revision-gutter` class, and that should get you started.

Comment: Well that was easy. Thanks, Mr. Kirby.

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches to solving the problem, which stems from your use of `float: right`. You can either 1) Move the `.theater` gray box above the sidebar, and it will properly float to the right side of it, or 2) You can change the sidebar to `float: left`, remove the float from the gray box, and add a left margin.

[Here's an example of the second approach.](http://jsfiddle.net/PxwBH/)

You could also float both the sidebar and the gray box, but I would not suggest that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `float:left` or otherwise take the `.revision-gutter` div out of the flow

Floated left in my example: http://jsfiddle.net/trapper/f8yLh/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just add `float:left;` to the `.revision-gutter` and your done!

**YOUR CSS SHOULD BE**

```
.revision-gutter {
    width:270px;
    height:inherit;
    background-color:#333333;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    float: left;
}
```

And he [updated Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/f8yLh/2/)

Comment: Take a look at [this...](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/f8yLh/3/) perhaps it is your end goal!